Show that the volume of the prism $MNPQM'N'P'Q'$ does not depend on the position of the plane $(MNP)$
The problem
Let rectangular parallelepiped $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ of height $h$. A variable plane intersects the lateral edges $AA', BB', CC', DD'$ in $M, N, P, Q$. On the same lateral edges on the same side of the plane $(MNP)$ we consider $M', N', P', Q'$ so that $MM'=NN'=PP'=QQ'=a$
a) Show that the points $M', N', P', Q'$ are coplanar
b) Show that the volume of the prism $MNPQM'N'P'Q'$ does not depend on the position of the plane $(MNP)$
my idea
the drawing

a) The plane (MNP) intersects the plane's parallel planes (ABB'), (DCC') in MN and QP => $QP||MN$
by analogous we get that $MQ||NP$
We also know that $MM'|| NN', MM'=NN'=> MN||M'N'$ and by analogous we get $NP|| N'P'$ => $(MNP)||(M'N'P')$
by analogous we can show that $M'Q'||MQ=> M'Q'||(MNP)=$
This means that all these 4 points are coplanar because we can demonstrate that all 4 sides($M'N', N'P', P'Q', Q'M'$) are parallel with the plane $(MNP)$.
I don't know what to do for point b), and I'm unsure if my rationament for point a) is correct...

Your part a is incomplete. So what if $M'Q'$ is parallel to $MNP$? Do you also want the similar statements for the other lines? And how does that imply coplanar? (You have to connect the dots to complete the argument)

@CalvinLin We have the similar statements(that they are parallel to plane (MNP) ) for all of the 4 sides: $M'N',N'P',P'Q',Q'M'$

It's not in your writeup. Please edit it in and complete the argument. Not all of us are mindreaders.

@CalvinLin I edited my answer...

Part a looks fine. Part b should be "obvious". First, can you determine the volume, say by picking a special case? Then, try to explain why it is that constant.

@CalvinLin I absolutely have no idea for the b point. i assume that the special case you are talking about is when $(MNP)$ is parallel to $ABC$

Even better, when $(MNP) = (ABC)$, what is the volume? And why would this be a constant?

@CalvinLin In this case the volume would be $hLl$, in this case the volume would be a constant, because h,l,L are the sides of the parallelepiped...do you want to tell me that we have to express the volume in terms of h,l,L? If yes, how?

(You didn't define the variables, so I have to make some guesses what they are and I might be incorrect since not all of us are mindreaders) Not quite right? You want something like "base area X height". Also, where does $a$ come in? Or is the volume of that prism independent of $a$? (That would seem very surprising to me)

@CalvinLin the notation of a is in the problem... $a=MM'=NN'=PP'=QQ'$

Right, so if $a = 0 $, is the volume of $MNPQM'N'P'Q'$ still going to be $ h L l$ (which presumably is non-zero)? (Again, I don't know what L, l is, and I'm guessing that $hLl$ is the volume of the original rectangular parallelepiped?)

@CalvinLin Yeah, you are right, they are the sizes of the parallelepiped. How is this case going to help us solve the problem?

Well, what is the volume of $MNP\ldots $ first? I've been asking that for the past few comments and you've given no attempt at answering that. If you're just going to ignore me, I'm going to exit this conversation. $\quad$ If you know what that volume is meant to be, then you can see how for an arbitrary plane, can we get it down to that volume? That's much easier than showing 2 random prisms have the same volume. (Easier in a conceptual sense, though the proof is essentially the same.)

@CalvinLin i dont know how to express that volume i thought to express it as $Llh-V(ABCDMNPQ)-V(A'B'C'D'M'N'P'Q')$ is it ok???

Are you focusing on the case of $ (MNP) = (ABC)$? What does $MNPQM'N'P'Q'$ look like? What is the ratio of that volume over all of $ABC$?  $\quad$ Like I said, I'm exiting this conversation.

@CalvinLin In that case the volume would be $alL$ because we would have a  rectangular parallelepiped

(You seem to be making the assumption that we have a cuboid, instead of a generic rectangular parallelpepied which could be slanted) $\quad$ In the case of a cuboid, why would a generic $MNP\ldots$ have volume $ a l L$? How would you argue that? $\quad$ FWIW The idea you had of $ Lln - V(ABC\ldots ) - V(A'B'C"\ldots )$ could be used. Can we "collapse" the intermediate space?

@CalvinLin ooooo....i think i know how to solve it. so we 'colapse' that space and got that the volume we are looking for is $Llh-Ll(h-a)=Lla$ ( an observation that the big parallelepiped cant be slanted because is rectangular) but I don't know how to proceed in the case where $M', N',P'$  or   $Q'$ are outside the lateral lines...

1/ Hm, I'm out of touch with the exact definition of the term, though this result also holds for a slanted parallelepiped. 2/ Yes, collapsing that space works nicely. 3/ In the event that the new points are outside, just consider a much higher A"B"C"D".
